# Regression Analysis and Optimization in R

Tags: regression, modeling, optimization, simulation

I have the following table:

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("y x1 x2 x3 x4
                  40 5 10 8 2 
                  60 9 19 9 9 
                  75 18 27 19 5 
                  80 15 36 25 20 
                  115 25 45 39 30 
                  120 35 48 58 19"), header=TRUE)
```

My goal is to find parameters which affect y and to find max(y).

I did linear regression analysis and got that x1,x3 and x4 are the most significant in my model:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 28.72819    0.55194  52.050   0.0122 *
x1           3.23213    0.09732  33.211   0.0192 *
x2          -0.25882    0.06863  -3.771   0.1650  
x3          -0.61356    0.04154 -14.770   0.0430 *
x4           1.37197    0.05057  27.128   0.0235 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3601 on 1 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9999 
F-statistic:  9316 on 4 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.00777
```

Data set above is information for one month and my question is how can I maximize `Y` for next month, if parameters `x1,x2,x3,x4` I can change and `x1,x2,x3,x4>0`

Should I perform a simulation or optimization?

Comment: Set `x1` and `x4` to infinite and `x2` and `x3` to the smallest tolerable positive number.

Comment: As @Stephan's apt comment indicates, the question is ill-posed: the predicted value of `Y` can obviously be made as large as you like without limit. Of course the prediction is going to become more and more uncertain as you vary the $x_i$ further beyond their ranges in the data: that's what prevents this otherwise ridiculous-sounding conclusion from being useless. Stephan's comment also implies the answer to your explicit question--to use simulation or optimization--is that you should instead reflect on the appropriate uses of your model and you will push it beyond its limits at your peril!